# Tagging latex code for subsequent aggregation

Tags: macros, itemize

I'd like to tag portions of LaTeX markup throughout my document. At some point later, I'd like to replicate all of the tagged portions. As an example of my desired behavior:

```
\begin{itemize}
\tag{\item \textbf{This is the main point}}
\item This is not the main point
\item Neither is this
\end{itemize}
%
\begin{itemize}
\tag{\item \textbf{This is another main point}}
\item This is still not the main point
\item Nope
\end{itemize}
%
\aggregateTags
```

Which would ideally yield the following:

- **This is the main point**
- This is not the main point
- Neither is this
- **This is another main point**
- This is still not the main point
- Nope
- **This is the main point**
- **This is another main point**

To give context, I'm trying to take my first bullet of each slide of my beamer presentation which (spoiler alert) contains the main point of each slide. I'd then like to aggregate all of the main points to a final conclusion slide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks\mytags

\def\mytag#1{#1\global\mytags\expandafter{\the\mytags#1}}
\def\aggregateTags{\begin{itemize}\the\mytags\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\mytag{\item \textbf{This is the main point}}
\item This is not the main point
\item Neither is this
\end{itemize}
%
\begin{itemize}
\mytag{\item \textbf{This is another main point}}
\item This is still not the main point
\item Nope
\end{itemize}
%
\aggregateTags

\end{document}
```